# gensim doc2vec - How to infer label

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, doc2vec

I am using gensim's doc2vec implementation and I have a few thousand documents tagged with four labels.

```
yield TaggedDocument(text_tokens, [labels])
```

I'm training a Doc2Vec model with a list of these **TaggedDocument**s. However, I'm not sure how to infer the tag for a document that was not seen during training. I see that there is a infer_vector method which returns the embedding vector. But how can I get the most likely label from that?

An idea would be to infer the vectors for every label that I have and then calculate the cosine similarity between these vectors and the vector for the new document I want to classify. Is this the way to go? If so, how can I get the vectors for each of my four labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
model.docvecs['my_tag']
```

gives me the vector for a given tag. Easy

Comment: would you please edit your comment and add a minimal example starting from the document query to printing the similar tags

Answer (score 7):

The `infer_vector()` method will train-up a doc-vector for a new text, which should be a list-of-tokens that were preprocessed just like the training texts).

And, as you've noted, `model.docvecs['my_tag']` will get the pre-trained doc-vector for one of the tags that was known during training.

Checking the similarity of a new vector, against the vectors for all known-tags, is a reasonable baseline way to see what existing tags a new document is similar-to. The closest tag, or closest few tags, might be reasonable labels for an unknown document, as a sort of 'nearest-neighbor' approach.

But, note that the original/usual `Doc2Vec` approach is to give each document a unique ID, and let each ID-tag get its own vector. And then, perhaps, use those vectors with known-labels to train some *other* classifier that maps vectors to labels. (This might work better in some cases, if the "areas of the doc-vector space" that humans associate with a particular label *aren't* neat radiuses around a single centroid point for each label.)

Your approach of using, or adding, known-labels as doc-tags can often help. But also note that if you're only using 4 unique tags across thousands of documents, that's functionally very similar to just training the model with 4 giant documents – which may not be good at positioning those 4 vectors in a large-dimensional space (>4 dimensions), because there's not so much of the variety/subtle-contrasts that are needed to nudge the trained vectors into useful arrangements. (Typical published `Doc2Vec` work uses tens-of-thousands to millions of unique docs and doc-tags.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried the 'default' approach, i.e. assigning each document one unique ID and training the doc2vec model with these IDs as only tags. Note, when using this approach, I train on the english Wikipedia rather than my actual training corpus. Then I infer the vectors for my training corpus and train a SVM on it. I get reasonable yet not surprisingly good results, thus I'd like to go for the other approach. In my first experiments the new approach ('supervised' doc2vec) seems to work well, altough  I still have to find the best hyperparameters(which is not easy).

Comment: Do you know any good reference on how to find good hyperparameters? Currently I am just doing trial and error, but the hyperparameter space is too big and training takes too long to really feel like having found the best parameters.

Comment: Whether a model trained on Wikipedia works well for your docs could depend a lot on how well the domain/language/word-senses match. (More of your own data, or literature known to be from the same domain and written in the same style, might work best.)

Comment: Generally I've started with some coarse grid-searches over large lists of alternate parameters, often with smaller datasets, to get a general sense of plausibly-good parameters and likely directions/magnitudes of changes. (Of course, many parameters' optimal values vary with corpus size.) If the stakes/budget are large enough, you'd eventually automate an big search over many parameters on the full dataset, with a lot of parallel experiments on rented capacity.

Comment: A few non-intuitive things are that when your corpus gets really large, you may be able to make 'negative' quite small (as low as 1-3) to save a little training time and often still get good results. You can make `sample` quite small, even to something like 1e-6, to simultaneously save time (by dropping many more frequent words) and often still improve quality.